# Retrieve user image from cloud firestorage into Imageview

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'm using java to develop an android application, I'm using cloud firestore and firebase storage to store the user's profile picture.
When a user logs in, he/she can upload a profile picture and it will be loaded into an imageView, 
The images are successfully uploaded to the storage and successfully loaded into the imageView.

However, when I re-run the application and log into the account I uploaded the picture from, the picture can't be loaded into the imageView like before.

**Here's my code for uploading the picture:**

```
 if (mImageUri != null){
           file = mStorageRef.child(userId+".png");
            UploadTask = file.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(newOnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
 Toast.makeText(EditDonatorProfile.this,"Image uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  String Link = mImageUri.toString(); 
                    Upload upload = new Upload(userId,Link);
                    db.collection("profilePicture").document(userId).set(upload);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Choose a file first",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**and here's my retrieve code:**

```
DocumentReference documentReference1 =db.collection("profilePicture").document(userId);
        documentReference1.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
               String uri = documentSnapshot.getString("link");
          StorageReference storageReference = StorageReference.getReference("Images/"+userId+".png");
                if(uri == null)
                  return;
                       Uri link = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(uri));
                       Picasso.with(DonatorProfile.this).load(link).into(Photo);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what exactly isn't working the way you expect.  Is something failing?  Is there an error?  What have you done to debug this?

Comment: I will note that this is **not** going to give you a URL that you can load with Picasso: `String Link = mImageUri.toString();`

Comment: There's no errors and no  exceptions, i'll give you a scenario to understand

Comment: 1- user loggs in 2- user upload profile picture 3- user image is loaded into imageView 4- (Me developer) re-runs the application 5- user loggs in 2- user image is empty (can't be loaded).

Answer (score 0):

getCurrentUser().updateProfile(new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                        .setPhotoUri().build());